# Add parameter to link in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have my site setup so that if you are on a mobile you get a mobile rendered template.  To click to go to the main site you go

```
index.php?id=??&mainsite=1
```

This all works fine however I have a link at the bottom of my mobile template that says go to main site.  I want this to go to the main template page for the current page id eg

```
index.php?id=page:uid&mainsite=1
```

If I do

```
lib.mainsitelink= TEXT
lib.mainsitelink.data = page:uid
```

I get

```
www.example.com/uid
```

so when uid = 3 i get

```
www.example.com/3
```

but if i do the below code it doesn't work

```
lib.mainsitelink= TEXT
lib.mainsitelink.data = index.php?id=page:uid&mainsite=1
```

Is there a way to either do what I am trying to do or add a parameter to the end of the current url? eg what I am trying to do won't quite work on the news single page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I don't think that the cobj text  has a method data hence I would change that to the value method. Also when you want to use the getText data type you need to warp the variables with curly braces and then add the method insertData = 1 to it so everything inside the curly braces get replaced. Here is a complete example: http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/getText. Of course you can use a typolink cobject to replace the page id. Second you can add an additional link parameter (i.e. get-parameters) with the additionalParams method (with a typolink of course) or you can use a plain cobj text. Here is an example with a cObj image and stdWrap cObj typolink and tt_news get-parameters. It also opens a popup-window.

```
             40=IMAGE
             40.file=print.gif                 
             40.stdWrap.wrap = <div>|</div>
             40.stdWrap.typolink.no_cache = 1 
             40.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = page:uid
             40.stdWrap.typolink.parameter.wrap = | ,1 print
             40.stdWrap.typolink.additionalParams.cObject = COA
             40.stdWrap.typolink.additionalParams.cObject {

                  10 = TEXT
                  10.data = GPvar : no_cache 
                  10.wrap = &no_cache=|
                  10.required = 1

                  20 = TEXT
                  20.data = GPvar : L
                  20.wrap = &L=|
                  20.required = 1

                  30 = TEXT
                  30.data = GPvar : backPID
                  30.wrap = &backPID=|
                  30.required = 1

                  40 = TEXT
                  40.data = GPvar : tt_news
                  40.wrap = &tt_news=|
                  40.required = 1

              }
```

Comment: as I noted in my question this won't work for the news single page.

Comment: I posted some code I didn't test it with single page. Maybe it's because you use no_cache get parameter disabled?

Comment: TEXT has a data property; be careful with tt_news backPID,; you should not add no_cache to an url if you can avoid; L-parameter should be added via config.linkVars; you cannot pass the cHash because it is computed. adding an wrong cHash just deactivates the cache; there is no stdWrap property "typolinkno_cache"

Answer (score 2):

According to [typolink reference](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/5/#id553839) you need to use `additionalParams`

```
lib.myLink = TEXT
lib.mylink.value = Click me!
lib.mylink.typolink.parameter.data = page:uid
lib.mylink.typolink.additionalParams = &mainsite=1
lib.mylink.typolink.useCacheHash = 1
```

Keep in mind that **each** (even first) parameter in `additionalParams` begins with `&`. Most probably you'll need also make sure that it will generate cHash for proper caching.

Comment: This doesn't explain the use of gettext object but only explain additionalparams.

Comment: @Chiyou Yes, isn't it what he was asking about ? (additional params?) Again you're trying to prove thas OP was asking for something else, than he wrote in his question. there are thousand of possibilites and writing thousand of samples is not my job, as there're thousands of samples in the net.

Comment: No. It's just not a complete answer to solve his problem. I hope you can understand critics and btw. I see your score is high. That's not meant negative but you can improve you answer.

Comment: I would say this almost is complete answer and it's how the link is supposed to be created. The only thing it's IMHO missing is `lib.mylink.typolink.addQueryString = 1` so that other existing GET parameteres (e.g. UID of a news record) are added to the link.