# typoscript dynamic link parameter

Tags: typo3, typoscript, markers

i try to get  a page title in a parameter for a link like:

```
index.php?id=1&mainsite=development
```

the "development" is the page title

i've try it with:

[EDIT]

```
50 = TEXT
    50.value = get involved
    50.typolink{
        parameter = 28
        parameter.data = #you need something else than the title here
        additionalParams.dataWrap = &mainsite={GP:type}
        additionalParams.if.isTrue.data = GP:type
        useCacheHash = 1
        ATagParams = class='btn btn-primary btn1'
    }
```

from [Add parameter to link in typoscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919556/add-parameter-to-link-in-typoscript)

This call is in an COA and the link should become different GET params with name &type=get_involved or &type=realize. i thought, i take the title or subtitle for that.

How can i realize dynamic params in Typoscript ?

Thanks,

ShaoKhan

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution if anyone need it:

```
50 = TEXT
    50.value = get involved
    50.typolink{
      parameter = 28
      additionalParams.rawUrlEncode = 1
      additionalParams.data = field:header
      additionalParams.wrap = &type= |
      ATagParams = class='btn btn-primary btn1'
    }
```

it creates a link to page 28 and puts the GET param **&type=** at the end
the **wrap** contains the header of a part of the content

The link looks like this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?id=28&type=dread_disease
```

hope it'll help. **_*problem solved*_**

Answer (score 0):

```
50 = TEXT
50.value = get involved
50.typolink{
    parameter.data = #you need something else than the title here
    additionalParams.dataWrap = &mainsite={GP:mainsite}
    additionalParams.if.isTrue.data = GP:mainsite
    useCacheHash = 1
    ATagParams = class='btn btn-primary btn1'
}
```

You can not link to the title directly, because TYPO3 uses the UID of a page to generate internal links. Any approach using a real page title for the link would result in an external URL, which would not give you the option of additionalParams.

So you will either need a PHP based function that generates the UID out of the title, or you must provide more than just the title within your GP vars.